# RegEnumValue always throws ERROR_MORE_DATA for last value

Tags: c++, windows

No matter what, my call to RegEnumValue is always returning ERROR_MORE_DATA (234) on the last value for a key.

I am getting the size of the buffer necessary by using:

```
retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(hSubKey,          // key handle
                                      NULL,             // buffer for class name
                                      NULL,             // size of class string
                                      NULL,             // reserved
                                      NULL,             // number of subkeys
                                      NULL,             // longest subkey length
                                      NULL,             // longest class string 
                                      &valueCount,      // number of values for this key 
                                      &cLongestValue,   // longest value name 
                                      NULL,             // longest value data 
                                      NULL,             // security descriptor 
                                      NULL);            // last write time
```

Then I allocate my array:

```
currentValueName = new WCHAR[(int)cLongestValue];
```

Then I try to get the value:

```
retCode = RegEnumValue(hSubKey, j, currentValueName, &cLongestValue, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

and retCode is always 234 when j = 2 (the last indexed value).

Why am I always getting ERROR_MORE_DATA? It's working fine for the first two values in the key.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am very new to C++ so there could be something very obvious I am overlooking.

Comment: You've forgotten to leave an extra character for the terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegEnumValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 3rd parameter (**lpValueName [out]**):

> A pointer to a buffer that receives the name of the value as a
>   **null**-terminated string. This buffer must be large enough to include
>   the terminating **null** character.

[RegQueryInfoKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns just the value size in characters, so plain data, no string termination.

> A pointer to a variable that receives the size of the key's longest
>   value name, in Unicode characters. The size does not include the
>   terminating **null** character.

*ERROR_MORE_DATA* tells you that a buffer is too small.

There you are: increase your buffer for one more character to make space for the additional termination.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I've tried this. I tried to allocate my array using MAX_PATH as some code samples do online, but that didn't even work. Is it that I need to just give one extra character to the array, or do I also need to increase cLongestValue by 1 when I'm passing that into the method?

Comment: You need to increase your array size, so there's enough storage space for the characters + termination **and** pass the increased _cLongestValue_ because this value has to reflect the actual array size.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that out this morning. It makes sense. I think I might have tried allocating that way but not passing it into the method that way.